# How to test two HTTP requests in Jmeter without affecting the performance of individual requests and how to only record the results of one?

Tags: jmeter

I'm doing a performance test of a HTTP Patch Method Request using Jmeter called 'Update Person'. The case here is the Update Person is dependent on another request called 'Create Person'. Create Person will return a 'personId' as a response and I will use that id to send an update request. So I can't do a performance test with only the Update Person Request. Here is my Jmeter Test Plan Layout:

[Jmeter Test Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4Pgm.png)

When I run the test plan, the performance of both request is significantly slower than testing the Create Person alone. My questions are:

- Does testing two http requests affects the performance? If yes, how?
- Is there a way that I can test my Update Person request alone while the Create Person request is running in the background to get the personIds?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You can first run the create person alone and get all the required person ids in the csv. For this you can use the post processors and capture and write the output or take it directly from DB if it is there and you can.
2. Then, pass the created ids to the second request from the csv using CSV Data Set config.

Update:-

Use regex or any post processor for fetching the UserId then with in the same sampler use BeanShell PostProcessor to write the output to csv:-

Ex:-

```
CreatePerson = vars.get("Create_Person");
f = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/XXX/Users.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(CreatePerson);
f.close();
```

This can also be achieved with Groovy for performance improvement. I am not an expert on Groovy but you can find that on this site. Dmitri T has submit that many times.

Then, for reading it is very easy. Add "[CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)" before the samplers or on top to fetch the data. Column name need to be passed as variable where it is required like ${CreatePerson}

There is one more thing to capture the data instead of code. Use [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables). In the user.properties(under bin folder) file add a line in the end:-`sample_variables=CreatePerson`
Then, use simple data writer or view result listener to save the results in the csv. It should write the data in the csv. You can deselect all the data that is not required from the simple data writer/view result listener.

Comment: Thank you! I've actually thought of this, but I just need to make sure that there is no other way. If I will do this, I first need to learn how to save the personIds in the csv file then reading the csv file while I run the Update Person performance test. Thanks again.